# How to send BCC via MFMailComposeViewController in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, email, sdk, message, bcc

One part of my app sends an e-mail with an attachment. I'm using the MFMailComposeViewController class, and all is well.

I just would like to know if I can send a stealth BCC message to myself, just for statistics purposes to keep track of how many messages have been sent.

Thank you!

UPDATE: the user tc didn't understand what I was trying to accomplish. I DON'T WANT TO INVADE USER'S PRIVACY. I just need to keep track of EVENTS ON MY APP. I didn't make myself clear on what I needed.

Comment: Dear tc, please I'd appreciate if you read all my comments exchanged with MarkGranoff and you'll see what I meant. I'm new here and I don't have any bad intentions with my app users.

Comment: Even if you have good intentions, it's the wrong way to collect analytics data and may violate data protection laws in your country (as well as various legal agreements with Apple). Even if "invading privacy" is not your *goal*, a "stealth BCC" *is still an invasion of pricacy!* Your first thought should be "How can I do this without massive privacy problems?", not "How can I do this without the user being aware of massive privacy problems?".

Comment: What we have here is a problem with my English communication and my lack of programming skills and knowledge. Indeed, reading my question again the expression "stealth BBC" was a very bad way to express my thoughts. I do apologize for my bad English, anyways... But now I'm truly happy with Flurry services recommmen

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English using such an unhappy and bad expression as " stealth BCC ". My ignorance, my mistake, my negative vote, my loss. Anyway, I'm truly VERY happy with Flurry statistics services nicely recommended by Mark Granoff. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the `setBccRecipients:` method on your instance of `MFMailComposeViewController`?

Depending on the content of the e-mail message being composed, you might want to re-think sending a Bcc to yourself, unbeknownst to your users... Just sayin'...

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer. I tried that but I really would like that my statics e-mail address would not show up on the list. I don't want to know what my users could write on the message. I just need a way to know how many e-mails are being sent.

Comment: Yeah... Bcc is probably not the way to go then. Thinking outside the box, you could sign up for a free Flurry account (www.flurry.com) and setup an event that you then log when the user sends an e-mail successfully. Flurry is free for this sort of thing, and very easy to integrate. Then you can log in to Flurry and see all kinds of (anonymous) things about your users (in terms of location, platform, etc) and when and how many events are getting triggered from app use. (I have no connection with Flurry except as a user.) Good luck!

Comment: Great! This kind of anonymous data is all that I need. I'll give Flurry a try to see how it goes ;-)

Comment: I'm still testing my app. Will my tests show up at Flurry website right away? Thanks!

Comment: "Soon", I'd say. There should be little delay, assuming you've integrated correctly with your App key, and what not.

Comment: Thanks! I've imported the #import "FlurryAPI.h" to myAppDelegate.h and have put the  [FlurryAPI startSession:@"mykey"]; on the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method, with the key they gave me at the website. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help. I used Flurry for the first time only recently, but I have known about it for some time. It is quite nicely done, in terms of being able to get it going very fast, and the payoff (if you're interesting in analytics) is pretty high. Good luck!

Comment: the user tc didn't undertand my point. I don't want to invade user's privacy. I JUST NEED TO KEEP TRACK OF STATISTICS!

Answer (score 0):

You can track if an email was sent successfully without sending yourself a bcc of the message. Check the `didFinishWithResult` delegate method.

Comment: That was another great suggestion! Thanks The-Kenny, you really did get my point!